# Concatenate mail subject in PHP mailer

Tags: php, email, concatenation, mailer, subject

I have a form for users to submit their inquiry which will be sent as an email. As users are able to select their inquiry type, i wish to concatenate the inquiry type into the subject of the email.

```
$formname = "Website Inquiry Form";
$inquirytype = "Books";
$mail->Subject = $formname . ' - ' . $inquirytype;
```

When I submitted the form, I got this error, Mailer Error: SMTP Error: data not accepted.

Any advise? Thanks.

Comment: After 3 seconds of googling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880042/phpmailer-the-following-smtp-error-data-not-accepted

Comment: there is nothing wrong in your concatenation. Problem is elsewhere.

Comment: is it the smtp server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [Basic Example using SMTP](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebsmtp)
and [look at this too](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examples)

do like this

```
$sub = $formname.'-'.$inquirytype;
$mail->Subject = $sub;
```

to add `body` text use

```
$mail->Body = 'I'm Body text';
```

**Basic of use**

```
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "yourname@yourdomain"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "yourpassword";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp, basic wi
```

Comment: I tried the first example but it still doesn't work. i think the issue lies with the concatenation but i need to join the two variables together. Tried googling but do not have any solution.

Comment: that should work check did you include all part of it

Comment: i tried using $mail->Subject = $formname; and $mail->Subject = $inquirytype; both worked perfectly. but once there is a . in the Subject, i get the error.

Comment: @user558085 try this `$sub = "$formname $inquirytype";` and tell works or not

Comment: it works half the time, i'm suspecting its the SMTP configuration. T_T

Answer (score 1):

*Just declare one variable subject*

```
$subject = $formname.'-'.$inquirytype;
$mail->Subject = $subject;
```