# SMTP "Error: DATA not accepted from server!" Opencart 2.3 on InMotionHosting

Tags: php, smtp, opencart

I've installed a brand new `Opencart 2.3.0.2` on `Inmotionhosting` with all default settings except MAIL settings which I've tried many different combinations. Although it shows the `"Error: DATA not accepted from server!"`, but it sends mail successfully!

Hosting support center says that all everything is OK, so it should be a coding issue!

Mail Setting:

```
Mail Protocol: SMTP
Mail Parameters: -fnoreply@mywebsite.com
SMTP Hostname: mail.mywebsite.com
SMTP Username: noreply@mywebsite.com
SMTP Password: ********
SMTP Port: 587
SMTP Timeout: 5
```

Full Error details:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: DATA not accepted from server!' in /home/mywebsite/public_html/mywebsite.com/oc/system/library/mail.php:409
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mywebsite/public_html/mywebsite.com/oc/catalog/model/account/customer.php(81): Mail->send()
#1 [internal function]: ModelAccountCustomer->addCustomer(Array)
#2 /home/mywebsite/public_html/mywebsite.com/oc/system/engine/loader.php(178): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Loader->{closure}(Array, Array)
#4 /home/mywebsite/public_html/mywebsite.com/oc/system/engine/proxy.php(25): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#5 /home/mywebsite/public_html/mywebsite.com/oc/catalog/controller/account/register.php(21): Proxy->__call('addCustomer', Array)
#6 /home/mywebsite/public_html/mywebsite.com/oc/catalog/controller/account/register.php(21): Proxy->addCustomer(Array)
#7 [internal function]: ControllerAccountRegister->index()
#8 /home/mywebsite/public_html/mywebsite.com/oc/system/engine/action.php(51): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 /home/sabour in /home/mywebsite/public_html/mywebsite.com/oc/system/library/mail.php on line 409
```

Any idea how to get rid of this error?

Comment: can you review your php ini file as often this parameter "sendmail-t-i", the protocol used "Mail", port 25 is set

Answer (score 0):

I have commented above, but if this does not fix your issue, there is a series of config steps to work through below:

Here is the complete article which I obtained from:

https://opencartforum.com/topic/23861-resheno-yandex-takoy-yandex-ne-otpravlyayutsya-pisma-vydaet-oshibku-data-not-accepted-from-server/?page=2

Opencart 2.0+ fix

First edit the file catalog / controller / information / contact.php
Look for line:

```
$ Mail-> setFrom ($ this-> request-> post [ 'email']);
```

Change it to:

```
$ Mail-> setFrom ($ this-> config-> get ('config_email'));
```

What this will do is set the FROM field to be the same as your shop's main email address.

Now find this line:

```
$ Mail-> setSender ($ this-> request-> post ['name']);
```

Change it to:

```
$ Mail-> setReplyTo ($ this-> request-> post ['email']);
$ Mail-> setSender ($ this-> config-> get ('config_email'));
```

Now we need to edit system / library / mail.php file
You just need to change one line:

```
$ Header = 'Reply-To:? = UTF-8 B??'. . base64_encode ($ this-> replyto). '='. '<'. $ This-> from. '>'. $ This-> newline;
```

change it to:

```
$ Header = 'Reply-To:? = UTF-8 B??'. . base64_encode ($ this-> replyto). '='. '<'. $ This-> replyto. '>'. $ This-> newline;
```

There is also a similar issue here:

[phpmailer - The following SMTP Error: Data not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880042/phpmailer-the-following-smtp-error-data-not-accepted?rq=1)

Comment: 1st line is already as you explained. I changed 2nd line, but nothing changed. My OC version is 2.3.0.2

Comment: This has to be a port problem as everything else you have described sound correct to me. Try switching port in your ini file as the default is 25

Comment: Are you using a proxy and firewall?

Comment: I checked all possible options together with my hosting live support, but no chance!!!

Comment: Did you make sure your port numbers are matching in your php.ini and your SMTP port in mail settings?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about it.

Comment: I fixed the problem and explained it below. Thanks for your helps anyway!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**

In my case, the problem was `SMTP HOSTNAME` which actually should be the `primary domain name` of the shared host, not the `add-on domain`.

```
Mail Protocol: SMTP
Mail Parameters: -fnoreply@addon-domain.com
>>> SMTP Hostname: mail.primary-domain.com <<<
SMTP Username: noreply@addon-domain.com
SMTP Password: ********
SMTP Port: 587
SMTP Timeout: 5
```

I wonder why live support of InmotionHosting.com didn't realise this!